# fujixerox docuprint p115w driver

Tags: drivers, printing

any ideas as to the correct configuration to get either the pcl or postscript generic driver working.

CUPS printing works on the mac suggesting it should do from linux, and poking about the printer config there's some settings for pcl and postscript headers.

Sending generic pcl files seems to end up with the job being thrown away, and generic postscript results in a pile of blank pages ...

Answer (score 2):

For the Fuji DocuPrint P115W on Linux try:

NOTE: my printer IP is 192.168.1.156, so replace it with your printer's IP.

You can see the available ports for your printer on: http://192.168.1.156/net/net/service.html

Available service/Ports that should work for you:

- BINARY_P1
- TEXT_P1
- POSTSCRIPT_P1
- PCL_P1

So in the Linux Printer manager, use the following for PCL:

- **Device URI**: lpd://192.168.1.156/***PCL_P1***
- **Driver**: Generic PCL Laser Printer

[image: here is a screenshot]